# Katello/Foreman: unable to syncronize products or install software

Tags: redhat, foreman, katello

I have configured `foreman` with `katello` scenario and previously configured and synced some repositories and content views (for Red Hat 5 server).

Suddenly, after running some synchronization tasks, the logs returns:

```
2016-12-30 17:12:14 0b8fc582 [app] [E] RuntimeError: 
There was an issue with the backend service pulp: 404 Resource Not Found.

# hammer ping

candlepin:

    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 112ms

candlepin_auth:

    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 79ms

pulp:

    Status:          FAIL
    Server Response:

foreman_tasks:

    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 40ms
```

I searched on google, community forums and mailing lists with no accurate results, also restarted all included services.

How can I workaround or solve this issue?

***Software Info:***

Foreman version: foreman-1.13.2-1
Katello version: katello-3.2.1-1

Red Hat Enterprise Linux  7.2

Answer (score 1):

I have found the root issue of pulp not loading/pinging correctly. I have found that pulp.conf was deleted by foreman in the path /etc/httpd/conf.d/. After adding the content, and also restarting apache httpd, it worked correctly and I can now sync or install any package to the servers.

Sharing the content of pulp.conf:

```
#
# WARNING: THIS CONFIGURATION WAS GENERATED BY KATELLO-CONFIGURE TOOL,
# CHANGES WILL LIKELY BE OVERWRITTEN.
#

# Apache configuration file for pulp web services and repositories

AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl 
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt

# allow older yum clients to connect, see bz 647828 SSLInsecureRenegotiation on

WSGIProcessGroup pulp 
WSGIApplicationGroup pulp 
WSGIDaemonProcess pulp user=apache group=apache processes=3 display-name=%{GROUP}

# DEBUG - uncomment the next 2 lines to enable debugging
#WSGIRestrictStdin Off
#WSGIRestrictStdout Off

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi 
WSGIScriptAlias /pulp/api /usr/share/pulp/wsgi/webservices.wsgi 
WSGIImportScript /usr/share/pulp/wsgi/webservices.wsgi process-group=pulp application-group=pulp

<Directory /usr/share/pulp/wsgi>   
Require all granted 
</Directory>

<Files webservices.wsgi>
 WSGIPassAuthorization On
 WSGIProcessGroup pulp
 WSGIApplicationGroup pulp
 SSLRenegBufferSize  1048576
 SSLRequireSSL
 SSLVerifyDepth 3
 SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
 SSLVerifyClient optional 
</Files>

Alias /pulp/static /var/lib/pulp/static

<Location /pulp/static>
SSLRequireSSL
Options +Indexes
Require all granted 
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks this work,

```
# hammer ping
candlepin:      
   Status:          ok
   Server Response: Duration: 49ms
candlepin_auth: 
   Status:          ok
   Server Response: Duration: 48ms
pulp:           
   Status:          FAIL
   Server Response:
foreman_tasks:  
   Status:          ok
   Server Response: Duration: 583ms
```

copy this

```
#
# WARNING: THIS CONFIGURATION WAS GENERATED BY KATELLO-CONFIGURE TOOL,
# CHANGES WILL LIKELY BE OVERWRITTEN.
#

# Apache configuration file for pulp web services and repositories

AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl 
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt

# allow older yum clients to connect, see bz 647828 SSLInsecureRenegotiation on

WSGIProcessGroup pulp 
WSGIApplicationGroup pulp 
WSGIDaemonProcess pulp user=apache group=apache processes=3 display-name=%{GROUP}

# DEBUG - uncomment the next 2 lines to enable debugging
#WSGIRestrictStdin Off
#WSGIRestrictStdout Off

WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi 
WSGIScriptAlias /pulp/api /usr/share/pulp/wsgi/webservices.wsgi 
WSGIImportScript /usr/share/pulp/wsgi/webservices.wsgi process-group=pulp 
application-group=pulp

<Directory /usr/share/pulp/wsgi>   
Require all granted 
</Directory>

<Files webservices.wsgi>
 WSGIPassAuthorization On
 WSGIProcessGroup pulp
 WSGIApplicationGroup pulp
 SSLRenegBufferSize  1048576
 SSLRequireSSL
 SSLVerifyDepth 3
 SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
 SSLVerifyClient optional 
</Files>

Alias /pulp/static /var/lib/pulp/static

<Location /pulp/static>
SSLRequireSSL
Options +Indexes
Require all granted 
</Location>
```

after restart , systemctl restart httpd

ping again

```
# hammer ping
candlepin:      
    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 46ms
candlepin_auth: 
    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 48ms
pulp:           
    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 204ms
foreman_tasks:  
    Status:          ok
    Server Response: Duration: 1019ms
```